# Retuning an arraylist with objects specified parameters from another constructor

Tags: java, arraylist, get

I have a class carDealership and there is an array list for all the cars with it's make year, model, horsepower, etc etc.

```
    inventory.add(new Lamborghini(1971, "urraco", 371.3, false));
    inventory.add(new Lamborghini(1971, "urraco", 371.3, false));
    inventory.add(new Lamborghini(1973, "countache", 373.3, false));
    inventory.add(new Lamborghini(1974, "silhouette", 374.3, false));
    inventory.add(new Lamborghini(1975, "jalpa", 375.3, true));
```

And so on. I was asked to complete this get method

```
    public ArrayList<Lamborghini> getCarsFromThisYear(int year)
```

with the conditions of returning an empty arraylist if there are no lamborghini objects with the specific model year and returning a arraylist of all the lamborghini obects with the specific model year.

I started off doing something like this..

```
    public ArrayList<Lamborghini> getCarsFromThisYear(int year){
        for(Lamborghini cars : inventory)
        { 
            if(cars.getModelYear() == year){

            }           
        }
    }
```

but had no idea what to put into that if statement, what to return, or even if I was on the right path.

Any suggestions or guidance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest:

```
public ArrayList<Lamborghini> getCarsFromThisYear(int year) {
   ArrayList<Lamborghini> thisYearLamb = new ArrayList<Lamborghini>();
   for(Lamborghini cars : inventory)
   { 
      if(cars.getModelYear() == year) {
         thisYearLamb.add(cars);
      }
   }          

   return thisYearLamb;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to put your result in a new list. So at the top create a new list like `ArrayList<Lamborghini> result = new ArrayList<Lamborghini>();`. You want to add the matches to the list, take a look at the [JavaDocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) to see how to do that.

Also, you have one minor bug: you should do `cars.getModelYear().equals(year)`.

Answer (score 0):

You should be returning an ArrayList of objects. So create an ArrayList and add each car which match the condition to the list. Return that list at the end.

```
public ArrayList<Lamborghini> getCarsFromThisYear(int year){
        ArrayList<Lamborghini> list = new ArrayList<Lamborghini>();
        for(Lamborghini car : inventory)
        { 
            if(car.getModelYear() == year){
                list.add(car);
            }           
        }
        return list;
    }
```

If you are using Java 8:

```
public List<Lamborghini> getCarsFromThisYear(int year){
    return inventory.stream().filter(car -> car.getModelYear() == year).collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```